# XOR circulant matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector, circulant-matrices

Take a function $f: Z_N\rightarrow R$.  Construct an $N \times N$ matrix where the $(i,j)$th element of the matrix is $f(i-j)$, where $i-j$ is interpreted mod $Z_N$.  The resulting matrices are precisely the circulant matrices.

Suppose, instead, that $N=2^n$.  We could perform the analogous construction where we interpret $i-j$ over $Z_2^n$.  Or, to paraphrase, we interpret $i$ and $j$ as strings of $n$ bits and put $f(i\oplus j)$ in the $(i,j)$th entry of the matrix, where $\oplus$ is a bitwise XOR.

My question is: is there a standard name for the second class of matrices?

Or, in pictures, if this is a circulant matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h\\
h&a&b&c&d&e&f&g\\
g&h&a&b&c&d&e&f\\
f&g&h&a&b&c&d&e\\
e&f&g&h&a&b&c&d\\
d&e&f&g&h&a&b&c\\
c&d&e&f&g&h&a&b\\
b&c&d&e&f&g&h&a
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then what is this matrix?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h\\
b&a&d&c&f&e&h&g\\
c&d&a&b&g&h&e&f\\
d&c&b&a&h&g&f&e\\
e&f&g&h&a&b&c&d\\
f&e&h&g&b&a&d&c\\
g&h&e&f&c&d&a&b\\
h&g&f&e&d&c&b&a\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(The motivation arose from looking for a simple class of matrices that share the same eigenvectors, like circulant matrices do.  The matrices above seem to relate to the Hadamard transform in the same way that circulants do to the discrete Fourier transform.)

Comment: Search for the term "G-circulant matrix". Here's an example: http://alea.impa.br/articles/v9/09-18.pdf.

Comment: @Flounderer Thank you!  That's even better.  The "G" in "G-circulant" refers to an arbitrary group; for $G=Z_2^n$, it reduces to my question.  If you want, put your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search for the term "G-circulant matrix".

Answer (score 3):

The object in question is also known as the [group matrix](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/articles/groupdet.pdf) or the [Dedekind matrix](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/Dedekind2.pdf), and it is closely related to the [Frobenius determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_determinant_theorem) which was at the origin of the representation theory.